# preg_replace/regex or string replace Greek Delta Symbol

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I've tried Notepad++, regular Notepad, and Dreamweaver and I cannot ASCII a Greek Delta symbol Which is `ALT+916`, I've successfully done other Greek characters, just can't get Delta. I can on Microsoft Word and other non UTF-8 text areas. I need a way to string replace a Greek Delta symbol to it's HTML entity or even just the string "DELTA". I guess string replace is not the right way to go about it, so I need a regex to `preg_replace` it in php or even use `replace()` in javascript, or is that also the incorrect way of doing that?

Comment: What are you finding the Delta symbol in? Sometimes the "delta" is a character substitute for formatting in MS Word docs, etc. The HTML equivalent of a delta is "&#916;" or "&Delta;" (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use:

```
$string = "this is delta: ¤";
echo str_replace("¤", "&curren;", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this as your delta (uppercase) symbol in the RegExp:

```
\u0394
```

or this as lowercase:

```
\u03B4
```

Comment: Works when I input from windows, not from mac. It'll work for what I need it for, Thank you!